# Dynamic remove Tab from TabHost problem on android1.5

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost

My codes like this:

public void removeTabForLogout(){

```
  if (tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount()==4){ 

      tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
      tabHost.clearAllTabs(); 
      tabHost.addTab(getTab1()); 
      tabHost.addTab(getTab2()); 
   }
```

}

private TabSpec getTab1(){

```
    if (mTab1==null){ 
        mTab1= tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1") 
            .setIndicator(...).setContent(intentForTab1); 
    } 
    return mTab1;
```

}

private TabSpec getTab2(){

```
    if (mTab1==null){ 
    mTab1= tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2") 
        .setIndicator(...).setContent(intentForTab2); 
    } 
    return mTab2;
```

}

I have 4 tabs in TabHost: tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 , when user logout i will remove tab3 and tab4, so i call the removeTabForLogout() , clear all tabs in tabHost and re-add the tab1 and tab2.

In android 1.5 and android 1.6, if current selected tab is tab1 when i call removeTabForLogout, there is a exception throw at tabHost.addTab(getTab1()):

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(205): java.lang.IllegalStateException: View com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@437aba18 has already been added to the window manager.

at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:125)

........

at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)

at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:210)

at aitao.mobile.android.actMain.removeTabForLogout(actMain.java:266)

But removeTabForLogout() works fine in android 2.0 and later version.

I can't find any usefull information on Google. Does any one can help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the lines the stack trace quotes as your issues it's difficult to answer. In the errors reading at TabHost.java:320 & TabHost.java:210 however it tells me that your code in Class "actMain" in line 266 your code is causing your error. I would consider reviewing that line.

Also if you are looking at Tab 1 when you remove it, just to reinstate it... couldn't you just leave Tab 1 and Tab 2 and not recreate them right after removing?